# Reverse sort order for part of a key

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to sort a list of objects. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
mylist = [aobject, bobject, cobject]
mylist.sort(key=mykey)
def mykey(sortelem):
    attribute1 = sortelem.attribute1
    attribute2 = sortelem.attribute2
    return (attribute1, attribute2)
```

Now I want to sort by `attribute1` ascending, but `attribute2` descending. I can always just do something like this:

```
return (attribute1, -1 * attribute2)
```

But that seems very unpythonic. I have searched the web, but it is a very hard thing to search for.

Comment: That's pretty much how you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: You can sort twice, adding a `reversed=True` argument where needed. Sort by the tiebreaker first. This works because sorting is stable in Python.

---

Using `- attribute2` instead of `attribute2` inside the tuple is the easiest way *if `attribute2` is a number.*

If `attribute2` is a string, or something else that cannot be multiplied by `-1` in a meaningful way, then this trick doesn't work.

However, note that `lst.sort` and `sorted` are guaranteed to be [stable sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) in python. In particular, this means that the two following code snippets are equivalent:

```py
# SORT ACCORDING TO A TUPLE
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

# SORT TWICE
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Note how in the second version, we sorted by the tie-breaker first, then by the main criterion.

With the first version, we can sort in decreasing order of one of the two criterion by multiplying it by -1, if this criterion is numeric:

```py
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
```

With the second version, however, we can sort in decreasing order of one of the two criterion, using optional argument `reverse=True`, and this works for numbers as well as for other types, for instance strings.

```py
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Finally, note that instead of defining a custom function with `def` or `lambda` to use as the sorting key, you can use `operator.itemgetter` or `operator.attrgetter`.

For instance, the following two code snippets are equivalent:

```py
# FIRST VERSION
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

# SECOND VERSION
from operator import itemgetter
l.sort(key=itemgetter(0, 1))
```

The following three code snippets are equivalent:

```py
# FIRST VERSION
def mykey(x):
    x1 = x.attribute1
    x2 = x.attribute2
    return (x1, x2)
l.sort(key=mykey)

# SECOND VERSION
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x.attribute1, x.attribute2))

# THIRD VERSION
from operator import attrgetter
l.sort(key=attrgetter('attribute1', 'attribute2'))
```

Comment: TL;DR: You can sort twice, adding a reversed=True argument. Sort by the tiebreaker first. This works because sorting is stable in Python.  Thanks for the answer Stef, what I commented here is what I got out of it (:

Comment: @mteam88 I added your TL;DR at the top of the answer.

Comment: What about sorting list like: `[("bcdes", 123), ("dafds", 32432), ("dsnt", 2305)]`, where you cannot apply "-1" on one of the attributes? Any one-liner solution than sorting twice?

Comment: @JeffXi If you want to reverse the order for all the attributes, then you can sort once with `reverse=True`. If you want to reverse the order for some attributes but not all, then I don't know a simpler solution than multiplying by -1 or sorting twice. Theoretically you could come up with some transformation that inverses the order strings are compared, but this sounds more complicated than sorting twice.

Comment: @JeffXi Or you could define a wrapper class `Inversed` that inverses the comparison operators and use it as the transformation: `>>> from functools import total_ordering
>>> @total_ordering
... class Inversed:
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = x
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return (self.x == other.x)
...     def __lt__(self, other):
...         return (other.x <= self.x)` and then `l = [("bcdes", 123), ("dafds", 32432), ("dafds", 3400), ("dsnt", 2305)]; r = sorted(l, key=lambda p: (Inversed(p[0]), p[1])); print(r)`